# Stray start tag "span" w3validaor error

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have below code which throws :  Stray start tag "span" and Stray start tag "i"  error in w3cvalidation (https://validator.w3.org/), would love to hear your suggestion to fix this

```html
 <select id="sort" class="dropdown-sorted">
     <option value="">SELECT</option>
     <option value="1">test1 <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></option>
     <option value="2">test 2  <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></option>
     <option value="3">test 3 <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></option>
     <option value="4">test 4 <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></option>
     <option value="5">test 5 <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></option>     
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: It is not valid to use element inside an `option` element, just text

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not valid having anything but text inside an `option` element, remove your `span` and `i` and the error will go away.

*Do note in your code that the render effect of the `span` or the `i` doesn't display as it would being outside the very same*

```html
 <select id="sort" class="dropdown-sorted">
     <option value="">SELECT</option>
     <option value="1">test 1</option>
     <option value="2">test 2</option>
     <option value="3">test 3</option>
     <option value="4">test 4</option>
     <option value="5">test 5</option>     
    </select>
```